# How to ping from EC2 instance to on-premises Windows Server using AWS VPN?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vpn, amazon-vpc, aws-dms

By following the link below, I have successfully setup Windows Server 2012 R2 as a Customer Gateway.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/adminguide/customer-gateway-windows-2012.html

I am able to ping the EC2 instance from my on-premises Windows Server. However, I want to do the vice-versa i.e., to ping the on-premises Windows Server IP from EC2 inside instance (RDP). May I know how to do this please?

I logged into EC2 instance through RDP. Pinged my on-premises Windows Server from there (192.168.X.X) but it returned 'Request timed out'.

Why do I need this?

I am doing all these because I want to migrate & replicate data automatically from my on-premises SQL Server to DB in Cloud. I decided to use AWS Database Migration Service (DMS). In order to set source endpoint (on-premises SQL Server), I need to let AWS communicate to my on-premises network through private IP. DMS should recognize 192.168.X.X\MSSQLServer.

Comment: Looks like a security group issue, can you detail your security groups?

Comment: Check outbound filters on your security group (but by default should allow everything).  Check your NACL to ensure it allows proper inbound/outbound traffic since it is stateless.  Check your Windows firewall in your Windows Server to ensure it will allow inbound ICMP.

Comment: Rather than trying to get Ping going, you could concentrate on trying to get the DMS connection going. Just because Ping works doesn't mean that other connections will work.

Comment: @programmerj - Please add answer. Let me accept that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Check outbound filters on your security group (but by default should allow everything).
- Check your NACL to ensure it allows proper inbound/outbound traffic since it is stateless.
- Check your Windows firewall in your Windows Server to ensure it will allow inbound ICMP.

Comment: It worked after I executed the following commands: 1) netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="ICMP Allow incoming V4 echo request" protocol=icmpv4:8,any dir=in action=allow 2) netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="ICMP Allow incoming V6 echo request" protocol=icmpv6:8,any dir=in action=allow